# Append dataframe to end of each dataframe in a list of dataframes in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to add one row to the end of each dataframe in a list of dataframes. In this example, I would like to add the column names as a new row to the bottom of each dataframe in the list of dataframes I created by `group_split`.

```
library(dplyr)

col_names1 <- as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(colnames(iris))))
colnames(col_names1) <- unlist(col_names1[1, ])
rownames(col_names1) <-""

iris %>%
  group_split(Species) %>%
  bind_rows(col_names1) #errors out: Error: Column `Sepal.Length` can't be converted from numeric to factor
```

I would like to end up with a list of dataframes, each with their column names as a new row at the bottom of each dataframe in the list.

Comment: *"add the column names as a new row"* will change all of your data to `character`, so no more numbers. Is that what you want?

Comment: your're right, it will, but thats ok.

Comment: Perhaps you want the *representation* of the data instead of how it is stored? For instance, showing `data.table::as.data.table(x)` will typically *show* the column names below the data as well as above it when there are more than 20 rows.

Comment: @r2evans actually this is for an output into an excel file thats a report so not for any analysis in R -thus the column types arent important and not about presentation. Having said that, I didnt know about `as.data.table()` displaying data like that, thats great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is the type difference.  We can convert to same type and then do the `bind_rows`. Also, as we are splitting into a `list` of `data.frame`, we need to loop over the `list` (`map`) and apply the `bind_rows`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
iris %>% 
    group_split(Species) %>%
    map(~ bind_rows(.x %>%
                           mutate_all(factor), col_names1))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 51 x 5
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# * <fct>        <fct>       <fct>        <fct>       <fct>  
# 1 5.1          3.5         1.4          0.2         setosa 
# 2 4.9          3           1.4          0.2         setosa 
# 3 4.7          3.2         1.3          0.2         setosa 
# 4 4.6          3.1         1.5          0.2         setosa 
# 5 5            3.6         1.4          0.2         setosa 
# 6 5.4          3.9         1.7          0.4         setosa 
# 7 4.6          3.4         1.4          0.3         setosa 
# 8 5            3.4         1.5          0.2         setosa 
# 9 4.4          2.9         1.4          0.2         setosa 
#10 4.9          3.1         1.5          0.1         setosa 
# … with 41 more rows

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 51 x 5
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
# * <fct>        <fct>       <fct>        <fct>       <fct>     
#...
```